# Alias not saved after reboot

Tags: linux, alias, xubuntu

I did

```
r00t@wutdo~$ alias daoc='mono "~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/DAoC/Portal.exe"'
r00t@wutdo~$ daoc
```

Works fine and dandy but after reboot the alias isn't saved.

```
r00t@wutdo:~$ alias
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal 
|| echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*
alert$//'\'')"'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

How can I set a permanent alias?

Comment: I fail to see how running the game Dark Age of Camelot has anything to do with servers.

Answer (score 9):

Put it in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases` depending on your setup (or `.zshrc`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

To edit the `.bashrc` file you can follow the below steps:

```bash
ls -al .bashrc >>> 
vi .bashrc
```

At the end of the file, enter the alias command:

```bash
:wq >>>
```

to save and exit the VI editor. Then run:

```bash
source ~/.bashrc
```